# Binding Socket to any existing address on specific subnet

Tags: java, sockets

I have a java application in which I want to receive a udp broadcast telegram in a known subnet, for example 192.168.x.x (255.255.0.0). If I know the IP of the machine which is running the application, the following works (assuming the IP of the machine is 192.168.10.1)

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.10.1");
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2222, ip);
```

But if the IP is not fix, maybe from a dhcp server, how could I create a socket which is bounded to the ip which the machine gets from the dhcp server. There may be other interfaces on other subnets, so if I will use

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2222);
```

the socket is not surely bounded to the ip in the subnet with 192.168.x.x.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Why? If you bind to 0.0.0.0 you will receive from anywhere. In what way doesn't that meet your objective?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the wildcard, I thought binding to 0.0.0.0 will bind actually to an existing like 192.168.10.1, but as I understand now, it will bind to 0.0.0.0 which is any. That would meet indeed my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your problem is to get the address assigned to an interface. I suppose you have more than one interface and you want to select one.

Also note by using `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2222);` you are binding to the wildcard address that often mean any and should work in many cases

From Oracle documentation [List Network interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html) you can retrieve inetAddress from different interfaces

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
            out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
        }
        out.printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: Let's say I have two interfaces, one 192.168.10.1 and one 10.254.10.1. If I use `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2222);` I would be able to receive telegrams over both interfaces (with port 2222)?

Comment: `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2222);` was the simple solution. I misunderstood the term 'wildcard'.